# Additional nuance of より with time

Tags: nuances, particle-より

It seems to me that より has virtually no meaning when used as shown below.

Consider these:

Please come before five O'clock:

- 五時前に来てください
- 五時**より**前に来てください

Please come after five O'clock:

- 五時後に来てください (*ungrammatical as observed by sawa)
- 五時**より**後に来てください

**(Question)** What does より add to the sentence? What additional nuance is there? And why is omission of より acceptable for 五時前 but not 五時後?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`より` has an important role. It means "from", but in languages like English, the word for "than" is morphologically distinct from the word "from". Don't think of an extra `より` being added but think that `より` is omitted in the examples without it. And in fact, `五時後` is ungrammatical.

As for why `五時前` is grammatical whereas `五時後` is not, I guess that it is because it is much more frequent to ask someone to come a little bit before a whole-hour time (to be ready for something) rather than a little bit after a whole-hour time. Thence, it is likely that expressions in the form `五時前`  had more chance to make it into a fixed expression.

Comment: What about 五時の後に..?

Comment: @gibbon That is ungrammatical.

Comment: I have revised my question to also ask about why omission of より is acceptable for 五時前 but not 五時後.

Comment: Maybe because we already have the expression 五時過ぎ to mean 'a bit after five'??